# Disabling css override from html style attribute

Tags: html, css, overriding

A height of an element is overriden in the html 'style' attribute by ext framework:

```
    <div class="class1" style="height: 900px;">
```

How do I set the height to 100% from css file? The following won't work since this rule is overriden by the html style attribute.

```
    .class1 {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Is it possible to disable override for this rule?

Answer (score 8):

yes it is possible

use

```
.class1 {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
```

Comment: @Oleg: you can do the thing by shankhan way, but it's not recommended practice, and should be used  with caution. There shouldn't be lots of place that defines the same rule.